# wp_logout_url redirects to incorrect page because of pagination

Tags: permalinks, pagination, redirect, logout

Following a [Wordpress Pagination](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress-pagination-a-primer/) tutorial, `wp_logout_url( get_permalink() );` no longer redirects to the correct page. Instead of redirecting to say `domain.com/page/2/`, it redirects me to one of the posts in the listed category.

Is there a way to fix this?

```
global $wp_query;  

$total_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;  

if ($total_pages > 1){  

  $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));  

  echo '<div class="page_nav">';  

  echo paginate_links(array(  
      'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',  
      'format' => 'page/%#%',  
      'current' => $current_page,  
      'total' => $total_pages,  
      'prev_text' => 'Prev',  
      'next_text' => 'Next'  
    ));  

  echo '</div>';  

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear, but I'm assuming you want a 'log out' url, that brings the user back to the current page?

[`get_permalink()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink) however, get's the permalink of the *current post* in the loop (if you're using it outside the loop, you'll find that it takes the user to the *last* post in the loop after they log out).

To get the url of whatever page you're currently on, you can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` (if there is a WordPress function that does this, apart from using [`add_query_arg()`](http://queryposts.com/function/add_query_arg/) I would like to know it...)

So try:

```
 wp_logout_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
```